# Django URL order

Tags: django, pycharm

iam stuck again I hope I will get useful help this time too.
Iam trying to run the app but it gives me URL configuration error something like this:

**Using the URLconf defined in pyshop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
products/
The empty path didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.**

I see a similar query in this platform but I couldn't find my answer
Iam using Django version 2.1

My code in pyshop.urls is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/', include('products.urls'))
]
```

Comment: Well you visit `localhost/`, so not `localhost/admin` or `localhost/products/`...

Answer (score 0):

You don't route `/` anywhere, and

> The empty path

implies that's exactly where you're visiting.

You'll either need to

- add e.g. `path('', SomeHomepageViewMaybe)`,
- or remove the `/products/` prefix to make the `products` app a "main" app (not that there's a concept like that in Django),
- or just navigate to `/products/` instead